# Conway's Game of Life - Gliders not moving

Tags: javascript, html, conways-game-of-life

So I've implemented a simple Game of Life in Javascript and canvas, and I thought it was working perfectly (fixed timestep, a temporary 'next board' to store changes until they're needed, etc.) but when I added a 'glider' pattern it didn't behave as expected. They shift slightly but then stop.

I've gone over the code a hundred times and can't see anything wrong, but I'm sure it's a simple error I'm making somewhere. Code below. Any advice much appreciated!

UPDATE:

I was failing to deep copy the array, as Jonas pointed out below. I've fixed that now, and the simulation now works as the Game of Life is supposed to. (Thanks Jonas!)

Updated code below. Unfortunately the glider issue is still there - they move correctly for the first frame of the simulation and then stop completely. If anyone can spot the remaining error I'd be very grateful.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const tableSize = 64;
const cellSize = 4;

let tickDelay = 60;

let table = [];
let loop;

let deadChance = 0.5;

const colors = {
 alive: '#f2b630',
 dead: '#333'
};

function init() {
 
 //build table
 table = [];
 
 for (let y = 0; y < tableSize; y++) {
  let row = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < tableSize; x++) {
   
   let randomAlive = true;
   if (Math.random() > deadChance) {
    randomAlive = false;
   }
   let cell = new Cell(x, y, randomAlive);
   row.push(cell);
  }
  table.push(row);
 }
 
}

function tick() {
 
 console.log("tick");
 
 table = table.map(row => row.map(cell => cell.tick()));
 
 render();
}

function render() {
 
 for (let y = 0; y < tableSize; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < tableSize; x++) {
   table[x][y].draw();
  }
 }
}

function start() {
 console.log("Starting");
 loop = setInterval(tick, tickDelay);
}

function stop() {
 console.log("Stopping");
 clearInterval(loop);
}

function reset() {
 console.log("Resetting");
 clearInterval(loop);
 init();
 render();
}

class Cell {
 
 constructor(x, y, isAlive) {
  //The x and y values are table indices, not pixel values
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.isAlive = isAlive;
 }
 
 tick() {
  
  let currentNeighbours = getNeighbours(this.x, this.y);
  
  let numAliveNeighbours = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < currentNeighbours.length; i++) {
   if (currentNeighbours[i].isAlive) {
    numAliveNeighbours++;
   }
  }

  
  switch (numAliveNeighbours) {
   case 0: this.makeDead(); break;
   case 1: this.makeDead(); break;
   case 2: break;
   case 3: this.makeAlive(); break;
   case 4: this.makeDead(); break;
   case 5: this.makeDead(); break;
   case 6: this.makeDead(); break;
   case 7: this.makeDead(); break;
   case 8: this.makeDead(); break;
  }
 
  return new Cell(this.x, this.y, this.isAlive);
 }
 
 draw() {
  
  if (this.isAlive) {
   ctx.fillStyle = colors.alive;
  } else {
   ctx.fillStyle = colors.dead;
  }
  
  let margin = 1;

  ctx.fillRect(this.x * cellSize + (this.x * margin), this.y * cellSize + (this.y * margin), cellSize, cellSize);
 }
 
 makeAlive() {
  this.isAlive = true;
 }
 
 makeDead() {
  this.isAlive = false;
 }
}

//Helper functions

function getNeighbours(x, y) {
 
 //return a list of all eight neighbours of this cell in North-East-South-West (NESW) order
 let result = [];
 
 //wrap at the edges of the table for each neighbour
 
 let targetX;
 let targetY;
 
 //get NORTH neighbour
 targetX = x;
 targetY = y-1;
 if (targetY < 0)
  targetY = tableSize-1;
 
 result.push(table[targetX][targetY]);
 
 //get NORTHEAST neighbour
 targetX = x+1;
 targetY = y-1;
 if (targetY < 0)
  targetY = tableSize-1;
 if (targetX > tableSize-1)
  targetX = 0;
 
 result.push(table[targetX][targetY]);
 
 //get EAST neighbour
 targetX = x+1;
 targetY = y;
 if (targetX >= tableSize)
  targetX = 0;
 
 result.push(table[targetX][targetY]);
 
 //get SOUTHEAST neighbour
 targetX = x+1;
 targetY = y+1;
 if (targetY > tableSize-1)
  targetY = 0;
 if (targetX > tableSize-1)
  targetX = 0;
 
 result.push(table[targetX][targetY]);
 
 //get SOUTH neighbour
 targetX = x;
 targetY = y+1;
 if (targetY >= tableSize)
  targetY = 0;
 
 result.push(table[targetX][targetY]);
 
 //get SOUTHWEST neighbour
 targetX = x-1;
 targetY = y+1;
 if (targetY > tableSize-1)
  targetY = 0;
 if (targetX < 0)
  targetX = tableSize-1;
 
 result.push(table[targetX][targetY]);
 
 //get WEST neighbour
 targetX = x-1;
 targetY = y;
 if (targetX < 0)
  targetX = tableSize-1;
 
 result.push(table[targetX][targetY]);
 
 //get NORTHWEST neighbour
 targetX = x-1;
 targetY = y-1;
 if (targetY < 0)
  targetY = tableSize-1;
 if (targetX < 0)
  targetX = tableSize-1;
 
 result.push(table[targetX][targetY]);
 
 return result;
}

//Patterns

function pattern() {
 
 //Set up the board using a random preset pattern
 console.log("Creating pattern");
 clearInterval(loop);
 
 //build dead table
 table = [];
 
 for (let y = 0; y < tableSize; y++) {
  let row = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < tableSize; x++) {
   
   let cell = new Cell(x, y, false);
   row.push(cell);
  }
  table.push(row);
 }
 
 //add living cells for patterns
 
 //Blinker
 
 table[1][0].isAlive = true;
 table[2][0].isAlive = true;
 table[3][0].isAlive = true;
 
 /*
 //Glider
 
 table[1][1].isAlive = true;
 table[2][2].isAlive = true;
 table[2][3].isAlive = true;
 table[3][2].isAlive = true;
 table[3][1].isAlive = true;
 
 
 table[12][12].isAlive = true;
 table[13][13].isAlive = true;
 table[14][13].isAlive = true;
 table[13][14].isAlive = true;
 table[12][14].isAlive = true;
 */
 
 render();
 
}

//Build board and render initial state
init();
render();
```

```css
html {
 background: slategray;
}

.game {
 background: #ddc;
 border-radius: 2px;
 
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 10%;
    display: block;
    
}

h1 {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

button {
 text-align: center;
 
 padding: 12px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 12px;
    display: block;
}

.controls {
 display: flex;
 width: 300px;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Conway's Game of Life</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
 
    <body>
  <h1>Conway's Game of Life</h1>
  <canvas id="canvas" class="game" width="319px" height="319px"></canvas>
  
  <div class="controls">
   <button onclick='start()'>Start</button>
   <button onclick='stop()'>Stop</button>
   <button onclick='reset()'>Reset</button>
   <button onclick='pattern()'>Pattern</button>
  </div>
  
  <script src="js/game.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The topic of the game isn't important enough to be part of the title.  Neither is what you call the control. What we're looking for instead is what *actually* isn't working. Is a div (or some other element) not moving when you change it's position? If so, have you proven that you are actually changing the position?

Comment: Debug the program until you see something happen which you did not expect and then you can ask a specific question about that.

Comment: @kevin I disagree. The error isn't obvious to spot, and it matters that this should be Conways game of Life as every serious programmer heard of it, so everyone knows what this algorithm should do.

Comment: @csmckelvey "sliders don't move" is quite accurate

Comment: That's an accurate problem description, not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throughout the code, you're accessing the grid by `x`, then `y` coordinate. In order for that to work, the grid should be defined as an array of columns, not array of rows.

As a quick fix, I simply swapped `x` and `y` when defining the grid in `init()` and `pattern()`. You'll probably want to rename your variables to reflect the intention.

---

There's a big issue with this part of the `tick` function. You're changing the value of `isAlive` property of a tile *before* the other tiles were checked for their future states.

> ```
> switch (numAliveNeighbours) {
>    case 0: this.makeDead(); break;
>    case 1: this.makeDead(); break;
>    case 2: break;
>    case 3: this.makeAlive(); break;
>    case 4: this.makeDead(); break;
>    case 5: this.makeDead(); break;
>    case 6: this.makeDead(); break;
>    case 7: this.makeDead(); break;
>    case 8: this.makeDead(); break;
> }     
> return new Cell(this.x, this.y, this.isAlive);
> ```

I fixed it with the following one liner as a personal preference, you can keep the switch statement as long as you're not directly changing the existing tile.

```
const isAlive = this.isAlive ? (numAliveNeighbours === 2 || numAliveNeighbours === 3) : (numAliveNeighbours === 3)
return new Cell(this.x, this.y, isAlive);
```

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const tableSize = 64;
const cellSize = 4;

let tickDelay = 60;

let table = [];
let loop;

let deadChance = 0.5;

const colors = {
 alive: '#f2b630',
 dead: '#333'
};

function init() {
 
 //build table
 table = [];
 
 for (let y = 0; y < tableSize; y++) {
  let row = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < tableSize; x++) {
   
   let randomAlive = true;
   if (Math.random() > deadChance) {
    randomAlive = false;
   }
   let cell = new Cell(y, x, randomAlive);
   row.push(cell);
  }
  table.push(row);
 }
 
}

function tick() {
 
 //console.log("tick");
 
 table = table.map(row => row.map(cell => cell.tick()));
 
 render();
}

function render() {
 
 for (let y = 0; y < tableSize; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < tableSize; x++) {
   table[x][y].draw();
  }
 }
}

function start() {
 console.log("Starting");
 loop = setInterval(tick, tickDelay);
}

function stop() {
 console.log("Stopping");
 clearInterval(loop);
}

function reset() {
 console.log("Resetting");
 clearInterval(loop);
 init();
 render();
}

class Cell {
 
 constructor(x, y, isAlive) {
  //The x and y values are table indices, not pixel values
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.isAlive = isAlive;
 }
 
 tick() {
  
  let currentNeighbours = getNeighbours(this.x, this.y);
  
  let numAliveNeighbours = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < currentNeighbours.length; i++) {
   if (currentNeighbours[i].isAlive) {
    numAliveNeighbours++;
   }
  }
    
        const isAlive = this.isAlive ? (numAliveNeighbours === 2 || numAliveNeighbours === 3) : (numAliveNeighbours === 3)

        return new Cell(this.x, this.y, isAlive);

 }
 
 draw() {
  
  if (this.isAlive) {
   ctx.fillStyle = colors.alive;
  } else {
   ctx.fillStyle = colors.dead;
  }
  
  let margin = 1;

  ctx.fillRect(this.x * cellSize + (this.x * margin), this.y * cellSize + (this.y * margin), cellSize, cellSize);
 }
 
 makeAlive() {
  this.isAlive = true;
 }
 
 makeDead() {
  this.isAlive = false;
 }
}

//Helper functions

function getNeighbours(x, y) {
 
 //return a list of all eight neighbours of this cell in North-East-South-West (NESW) order
 let result = [];
 
 //wrap at the edges of the table for each neighbour
 
 let targetX;
 let targetY;
 
 //get NORTH neighbour
 targetX = x;
 targetY = y-1;
 if (targetY < 0)
  targetY = tableSize-1;
 
 result.push(table[targetX][targetY]);
 
 //get NORTHEAST neighbour
 targetX = x+1;
 targetY = y-1;
 if (targetY < 0)
  targetY = tableSize-1;
 if (targetX > tableSize-1)
  targetX = 0;
 
 result.push(table[targetX][targetY]);
 
 //get EAST neighbour
 targetX = x+1;
 targetY = y;
 if (targetX >= tableSize)
  targetX = 0;
 
 result.push(table[targetX][targetY]);
 
 //get SOUTHEAST neighbour
 targetX = x+1;
 targetY = y+1;
 if (targetY > tableSize-1)
  targetY = 0;
 if (targetX > tableSize-1)
  targetX = 0;
 
 result.push(table[targetX][targetY]);
 
 //get SOUTH neighbour
 targetX = x;
 targetY = y+1;
 if (targetY >= tableSize)
  targetY = 0;
 
 result.push(table[targetX][targetY]);
 
 //get SOUTHWEST neighbour
 targetX = x-1;
 targetY = y+1;
 if (targetY > tableSize-1)
  targetY = 0;
 if (targetX < 0)
  targetX = tableSize-1;
 
 result.push(table[targetX][targetY]);
 
 //get WEST neighbour
 targetX = x-1;
 targetY = y;
 if (targetX < 0)
  targetX = tableSize-1;
 
 result.push(table[targetX][targetY]);
 
 //get NORTHWEST neighbour
 targetX = x-1;
 targetY = y-1;
 if (targetY < 0)
  targetY = tableSize-1;
 if (targetX < 0)
  targetX = tableSize-1;
 
 result.push(table[targetX][targetY]);
 
 return result;
}

//Patterns

function pattern() {
 
 //Set up the board using a random preset pattern
 console.log("Creating pattern");
 clearInterval(loop);
 
 //build dead table
 table = [];
 
 for (let y = 0; y < tableSize; y++) {
  let row = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < tableSize; x++) {
   
   let cell = new Cell(y, x, false);
   row.push(cell);
  }
  table.push(row);
 }
 
 //add living cells for patterns
 

 //Glider
 
 table[1][1].isAlive = true;
 table[2][2].isAlive = true;
 table[2][3].isAlive = true;
 table[3][2].isAlive = true;
 table[3][1].isAlive = true;

 
 render();
 
}

//Build board and render initial state
pattern();
render();
```

```css
html {
 background: slategray;
}

.game {
 background: #ddc;
 border-radius: 2px;
 
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 10%;
    display: block;
    
}

h1 {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

button {
 text-align: center;
 
 padding: 12px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 12px;
    display: block;
}

.controls {
 display: flex;
 width: 300px;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Conway's Game of Life</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
 
    <body>
  <h1>Conway's Game of Life</h1>
  <canvas id="canvas" class="game" width="319px" height="319px"></canvas>
  
  <div class="controls">
   <button onclick='start()'>Start</button>
   <button onclick='stop()'>Stop</button>
   <button onclick='reset()'>Reset</button>
   <button onclick='pattern()'>Pattern</button>
  </div>
  
  <script src="js/game.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

`slice()` does only shallow copy the array, that means that

```
 nextTable[this.x][this.y] === this // true
```

So you actually work with one set of cells, which won't work with Convays Game as it requires the cells to update based on the current state, and if there is only one table some cells will calculate their state based on the one of already updated neighbours. To change that, I would change the `tick()` method of the Cell so that it returns the next cell:

```
tick() {
  //...
  return new Cell(this.x, this.y, true /* false */);
}
```

Now in your main `tick()` function, just map the current table to a new one:

```
table = table.map(row => row.map(cell => cell.tick()));
```

Through that you don't need `nextTable` at all, as `table` will point to the old state until all cells were updated, then the table gets rewritten with the newly returned cells.

Comment: I'd perhaps take a slightly different approach, which is to have each cell maintain _its own_ state of "alive in this generation", and "still alive in the next generation".   This would avoid a lot of expensive object creation and garbage collection.

Comment: @alnitak the main point was to deep copy and that was the easiest change to reach that. For sure there are a lot of optimizations possible, e.g. a 2D Boolean array but thats beyond the scope of this thread :)